# PHP 5.5 $_POST array empty

Tags: php, html, post, intellij-idea

**EDIT: I used var_dump($_POST) *OUTSIDE* of the if statement.**

I've tried multiple solutions and none have worked, so this is my last attempt at resolving this issue. I have a form written in HTML sending data to a PHP script via POST, and the PHP script for whatever reason is only reading $_POST as empty.

Here is my PHP code:

```
if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
    die('test');
}
```

Here is my HTML form:

```
<form action="api/login.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="login-email" placeholder="Email">
    <input type="password" name="login-password" placeholder="Password">
    <input type="checkbox" name="login-remember-me" checked>
    <button name="login" type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

`var_dump($_POST);` returns:

> array(0) { }

`file_get_contents('php://input');` returns:

> login-email=user%40email.com&login-password=123123&login-remember-me=on&login=

Like I said, I have tried every solution I've come across after Googling this issue dozens of times. I am using PHP 5.5.32 NTS on Windows 10 Enterprise x64 with IntelliJ IDEA 15.0.4.

EDIT: Doing var_dump($GLOBALS), my input stayed within ["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"], didn't end up anywhere else. I have also tried using PHP 5.6.19 NTS instead of 5.5.32, which still did not fix this issue.

Comment: You can also dump `$GLOBALS` like so: `var_dump($GLOBALS);` to see where your input ended up.

Comment: This might sound stupid, but you may not be looking at `api/login.php` but a file with the same name in a different location...? try changing some text on the file you're editing now (and think is the right one), and see if it actually displays...

Comment: @JohnVegas check php.ini `post_max_size` value and ensure it is set to a valid value? i.e. `8M` vs `8MB`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the cause of the issue, but have not resolved the issue. Luckily, I was not the reason for this issue persisting. Seems like the issue is within IntelliJ IDEA's built-in webserver. Hopefully this helps someone else find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed that you don't have `value` in you submit button. Try putting value on it. That's why your PHP code is always not going inside the if statement because the `$_POST['login']` is not set.

As per your posting:

> login-email=user%40email.com&login-password=123123&login-remember-me=on&login=

So in your PHP code:

```
if (isset($_POST['login'])) { //there is no value on $_POST['login] so it skips the statement.
    var_dump($_POST);
}
```

But if you put a value on it like the sample bellow:

```
<form action="api/login.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="login-email" placeholder="Email">
    <input type="password" name="login-password" placeholder="Password">
    <input type="checkbox" name="login-remember-me" checked>
    <button name="login" value="login" type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

It will produce something like this:

> login-email=user%40email.com&login-password=123123&login-remember-me=on&login=login

Then you PHP if condition will be satisfied.

```
if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
    var_dump($_POST);
}
```

**output:**

> array(4) { ["login-email"]=> string(4) "test" ["login-password"]=> string(4) "test" ["login-remember-me"]=> string(2) "on" ["login"]=> string(5) "login" }

Comment: It was my hypothesis, but I have tested for this yesterday: `$_POST['login']` is set also with empty value (Tested on PHP 5.6.18)